# Bandwidth comparison between log shipping and transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, performance, replication, transactional-replication, log-shipping

Which technique uses more network bandwidth:

1. Log shipping
2. Transactional Replication

Can some one share any benchmarks for the same ?

What would be the Memory and I/O impact on the Primary server when we use any one of the technique ?

Thanks,

Piyush Patel

Comment: The two techniques do very different things, so I'm not sure it's worth the time comparing them.

Comment: Umm, I think that it's not an apple to apple comparison. Because Log shipping sends log backup files, while transactional replication sends commands for transactions (not the log backups) - using system procedures. One is using bandwidth, while the other needs small latency. They both depend on a good network, but on different characteristics.

Comment: I would also expect this to be different depending on the DBMS in use.

Comment: Based on the technologies mentioned and the OP's previous questions, I will assume the RDBMS in SQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your workload.  As a baseline, use Performance Monitor and log the network counters when not using Log Shipping or Transactional Replication and measure for 1 hour.  Then setup Log Shipping and use Performance Monitor to log the network counters for 1 hour.  Then setup Transactional Replication and use Peformance Monitor to log the network counters for 1 hour.  The network bandwidth that Log Shipping and Transactional Replication consumes is the difference between the collections and the baseline.  The same can be done for memory and I/O.

Answer (score -1):

I have measure the performance using PerfMonitor and outcome of it as below:

```
           20 docs ||   20 docs ||   200 docs
```

Log shipping:         9.88 MB ||    10.53 MB ||  28.55 MB

Replication:          6.14 MB ||    6.80 MB ||    17.71 MB

Log Shipping With:    7.86 MB ||    9.66 MB ||    18.17 MB

Compression

So Replication and Log shipping with compression takes almost same network bandwidth. I was measuring these things to know which technique help us to reduce the bandwidth cost from PROD to DR env.

Thanks,

Piyush Patel

Comment: Why have you accepted your own answer over the recommendation from @BrandonWilliams?

Comment: my bad, i just wanted to upload the image and system did not allow me to do that b'z i did not had a enough points so to gain some i did that. will not do from now onwards !!!